# Django relationship backward works without _set but not with

Tags: python, django

I have the following database tables:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=2000)
    exp_text = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    emailOnReply = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    comment_text = models.TextField()
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comment_text
```

When i have created an object of Comment and need to access the title of a story i would expect to be able to do this:

```
c = Comment.objects.all()
for com in c:
    com.comment_set.title
```

but django says that comment_set isnt defined. In the documentation it says that if you are tring to reach a field in the other database table where the foreign is not defined you can use the _set method where the word before it is the name of the class.

After trying different ways i found that this works:

```
c = Comment.objects.all()
for com in c:
    com.story.title
```

Since the foreign key is defined in Comment i dont see how that can work, but it does, and why doesnt the _set work. Since im working on an object in the model where the foreign key is defined and i need to go to the story then i would need to use _set according to the docs...when working with a story objects im able to refer straigt to the comment model when defining the related_name property so i dont need _set there either.. why doesnt _set work here?

Update:
I now got the relationship working backwards when using a story object and refering to the comment class by:

```
s = Story.objects.all()
for st in s:
    print st.comment_set.all()
```

I was using st.story_set instead of st.comment_set but i still find it weird that this works:

```
c = Comment.objects.all()
for com in c:
    print com.story.title
```

When trying to work from the story object i dont have any foreign key to the comment table (only a related name on the foreign key in the comment table) so i dont get the same access it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Actually everything is working as expected.
Comment object doesn't have a comment foreign key, it has a "story" foreign key.
comments are "pointing" to stories. as such - a comment only has one story, but a story may have a "set" of comments.

This is why `st.comment_set` works - because it "looks backward" to the comments pointing to it, while a comment just points directly to the story it is related to (i.e. `com.story`).

if you are interested in understanding why that works - see here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#how-are-the-backward-relationships-possible
  that's part of what makes Django's ORM so cool...

Answer (score 0):

Following relationships in Django is a bit implicit. Here are simplified versions of your models:

```
class Story(models.Model):  # instances have access to Manager comment_set (backward)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=2000)

class Comment(models.Model):  # has access to Story (forward)
    comment_text = models.TextField()
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story)  # stored in database as story_id, which refers to (implicit) id column in Story
```

Your database will look like this (unless you specify otherwise):

```
Story (table)
    id  # automatically inserted by Django, unless you specify otherwise
    title
    description

Comment (table)
    id  # automatically inserted by Django, unless you specify otherwise
    comment_text
    story_id  # points back to id in Story table
```

**FORWARD**

Instances of `Comment` have access to `Story` by matching `Comment`'s story_id column to `Story`'s id column (the latter being implicit to Django tables and not in your model but definitely in your database table, unless you have specified otherwise).

```
>>> c = Comment.objects.get(comment_text='hello, world')
>>> c.story.title  # c => story_id => row in Story where id == c.story_id
'first post'
```

**BACKWARD**

`Comment` has a ForeignKey pointing back to `Story`, so instances of `Story` have access to a Manager named `comment_set` that can follow relationships from `Story` to `Comment`.

```
>>> s = Story.objects.get(title='first post')
>>> s.comment_set.comment_text  # accesses Comment model from Story instance
'hello, world'
```

Or if you want to iterate over all `comment_set`s as you mention in your comment, try this instead:

```
>>> s = Story.objects.get(title='first post')  # returns a single, non-iterable query object
>>> for story in s.comment_set.all():  # each comment_set object can have more than one item
    print story.comment_text  # story does not have a comment_set attribute
'hello, world'  # my comment set here just happens to have one item
```

**UPDATE**

Or, based upon your comment, you want to take the iteration to one level higher, try the following:

```
>>> s = Story.objects.all()
>>> for story in s:  # iterate over top level
>>>     for row in story.comment_set.all():
>>>         print row.comment_text  # again, row does not have a comment_set attribute
'hello, world'  # again, my comment set has only one item
```

Comment: thank you for such a detailed explaination. I am however not able to get your last code to work when specifying this: >>> s = Story.objects.all()
>>> for story in s:
...     print story.comment_set.comment_text
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'comment_text'     ..ah dont know how to get nice formatting in a comment :/

Comment: @user2959896 I'm glad to help. I updated the answer above. See the very end of the answer for an example of how to iterate through the query_set. The *instance* s has a `comment_set`, but the query item `story` within that instance does *not* have a `comment_set`. (Also, you can use the back tick on your keyboard to format code in comments.)

Comment: @user2959896 Okay, my last edit does what you were trying to do when you received the error message above. You have to iterate through the top-level query set and the sub-level of query sets. I put a working example above. Best of luck!